# Android textview marquee like effect when setText

Tags: android, textview, effect, marquee

I want to make a textView (maybe another control?) that makes a marquee horizontal effect when replacing current text for another, I mean, when I set 'tv.setText("my text to replace");'  I want that the new text has a marquee effect replacing the old text, maybe cleaning previous.

any clue?